# Want to place 6 circles in a geometrical shape that's mathematically precise, but they don't align properly

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry, kineticjs

Relevant live-javascript/jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ekuyam/2/edit

I basically just generate points in a hexagon relative to the center of the canvas and then draw circles at each point in the hexagon, but on close inspection the circles don't align properly, it's not actually visible though unless you use large circles.

When I use small circles they seem to be placed on the canvas pretty accurately, as seen here:
[image]

But on closer inspection by using larger circles (kind of like zooming in), it's revealed that there is some inaccuracy in the math, as can be seen by the unwanted spaces/areas here:
[image]

The lines should align perfectly but instead I get some unwanted space. Why is this and how can I amend it?

Code:

```
function hexagon(w, h, p) {
  var points = 6;
  var width = w;
  var height = h;
  var angle = ((2 * Math.PI) / points);
  var hexagon = [];

  for (i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    hexagon.push({
      x: width * Math.sin(angle * i) + p.x, 
      y: height * Math.cos(angle * i) + p.y
    })
  }

  return hexagon
}

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: "container",
  width: 600,
  height: 600
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var group = new Kinetic.Group({x: 600/2, y: 600/2, draggable: false});

var radius = 1000;
var s = new Kinetic.Circle({
  radius: radius,
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  draggable: true
});
group.add(s);

var hex_points = hexagon(radius, radius, {x: 600/2, y: 600/2});
for (p in hex_points) {
  var s = new Kinetic.Circle({
    radius: radius,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    draggable: true
  });
  s.setPosition({x: hex_points[p].x - 600/2, y: hex_points[p].y - 600/2})
  group.add(s);
}

layer.add(group);
stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because  sin(2 * Math.PI) / 6 = sqrt(3)/2 which is an irrational number. However floats can only represent rational numbers (actually only with a denominator which is a power of 2). Thus you will always have some rounding error. If you magnify the circles enough then this rounding error becomes visible. In order to prevent this you need to limit the magnification.

If you absolutely have to get around it the simplest approach is to go for higher arithmetic precision.

Another approach would be to use the formula (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2 and solve it locally around the known intersection point WITHOUT using trigonometric functions. To be more specific, the function f(x,y):= (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 satisfies the conditions for the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) everywhere but x=x_0 and y=y_0. Notice that the circle example is contained in another wikipedia article on the [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). The example at hand is a holomorphic function thus the local inverse will also be holomorphic. Especially it has a good local approximation by [Taylor series expansion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). The point of this approach is that you do not draw the circle around the center put draw it "through the desired intersection point". Thus you can enforce that it will "intersect" this point. But keep in mind that he "intersection point" will be only an approximation as floats will never properly represent sqrt(3) or rational multiples thereof.

Now what to do? What I would do: once the magnification is such that there is only one intersection point on the screen I would cheat by substituting R such that R^2 = (x_i-x_0)^2+(y_i-y_0)^2 where (x_i, y_i) is the desired intersection point and "(x_0,y_0)" the center of the circle. Then I would proceed with the standard circle formulas.

A very much simpler approach would be to ensure that the circle lines get scaled as well. Thus for high magnification the imprecisions would be hidden under the "thick" perimeter of the circles.

Comment: But what if I sometimes need large magnification? Is there no way around it?

Comment: Isn't BigDecimal.js suppose to solve these kinds of issues? Going to try expressing the hexagon math in it..

Comment: Could you explain "(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2" and "solve it locally around the known intersection point" in more detail?

I'm not sure what values x and x_0 are, I'd guess one is the equivalent of "p.x" in my code and maybe the other is "600/2". And I don't know what "solving it locally around a known intersection" means, though I might be able to find out if I understood the equation.

But if I understand you correctly, it can be used to get what I want without using higher arithmetic precision, which would be awesome, cause I'd rather not use that.

Comment: @GuatamaDude if you know the radius `R` and the centre `(x0, y0)` of the circle, you can find any point `(x, y)` on your circle exactly by solving this equation. Then your circles will go through the same point.

Comment: @Alexandr hmm, I still don't understand how to apply it, if the center is (0, 0) then "(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2" can be expressed as "(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 = R^2" and then "x^2 + y^2 = R^2" and if R is 10 then we can do "x^2 + y^2 = 100", and.. randomly select something for x, 5? so "5^2 = 25", then move to the right "y^ = 100 - 25" which is "y^2 = 75" then "sqrt(75) = 8.660254038" and volla! I got a coordinate, I think.. (5, 8.660254038), but that's just a random coordinate, probably an accurate one but still random, so how do I get the coordinates I want? Probably have to use "angle" somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately not because of the way floating point arithmetic works. But you properly described my idea. I extend my answer.

Comment: @GautamaDude The idea is like this but you are right - this value will still be approximate, since your `sqrt` function and the floating numbers are not exact. Anyway, I do not understand your intention. With a computer you never-ever get exact solution. So, just find an acceptable precision.

Comment: @Alexandr But one step in my explanation was random, making x a 5, I need to make that step nonrandom, I don't care if it's not 100% accurate, just that this new method still represents a hexagon and is perhaps a bit better then my original method. I know now how to make 6 random points with this new method, but how do I use it to approximate a hexagon like I did with my original method?

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Would you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @UdoKlein I want to draw circles at the 6 edges of a hexagon, to do that I need the coordinates for the edges, I've already managed to do that but inaccurately, and it seems to me that "(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2" can give me more accurate coordinates (not sure if that's a misinterpretation on my part), but I don't know how to use it to generate *these* coordinates, I only know how to use it to create *a* coordinate.

Comment: @UdoKlein E.x. (x_0, y_0) = (0, 0), R = 10, gives me "x^2 + y^2 = 100", and it seems to me to complete this equation I need to make up a number for x or y and then calculate the remainder, but making up a number wont give me a the correct coordinate, it wont even give me an approximate coordinate, it will just give me *some* coordinate, that is though correct in the sense that it's actually somewhere on the edge of the circle, but I need 6 points at the edge of the circle that approximate a hexagon, not somewhere on the edge.

Comment: @UdoKlein So what I am trying to solve is how to use "(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2" to give me 6 points making up a hexagon instead of 6 points where the x or y value of the points is made up by me.

Comment: @UdoKlein "(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = R^2" -- "(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 = R^2" -- "x^2 + y^2 = R^2" -- "x^2 + y^2 = 100" -- *make up a number for x* "5^2 + y^2 = 100" -- "25 + y^2 = 100" -- "y^2 = 100 - 25" -- "y^2 = sqrt(75)" -- "y^2 = 8.660254038" -- (x, y) = (5, 8.660254038) <---- This is not a place on the edge of the circle that is part of the shape of a hexagon, because I just made up the number 5 and don't know how to complete the equation without making it up.

Comment: @GautamaDude I do not understand from which points of the circles you want to make a hexagon? From the centers? I am missing something from your question. Actually, the difference in precision between these two methods is probably not that big.

Comment: @Alexandr ahh, I just realized that the first point can be anywhere, so then my problem becomes, how can I, after making the first point, make another point in the correct location relative to the first point, and then 4 more, so I get 6 points in the shape of a hexagon..

Comment: @Alexandr okay I think I got it now, but I'm not sure if the results are that much different from my original method, need to do some testing. ||Edit|| exactly the same.. going to check if understanding what UdoKlein said "..I would cheat by substituting R such that.." might help.

Comment: @GautamaDude If you know your intersection point then do the UdoKlein algorithm. Then you get your cross point but the hexagon points will be approximate, although you will not see it.

Comment: By now I get the issue. What you want to achieve is just not possible. You can make the circles intersect in the center. But the hexagon corners will be on the rational grid. Thus you will not find a circle that will meet all 6 of them. In order to make this work the inner circle must become slightly distorted, that is you need an ellipsis. Visually this will be imperceptible but with 7 circles you can not achieve this with floats AND exact.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the float number storage nor the trigonometric functions can be the cause of such large errors.

What is more likely, is that the circle drawing routine that you use, is actually approximating a circle by 4 bezier splines. This is a very, very common speed optimisation in drawing libraries. You have calculated the centers nearly perfectly, but the circles are simply not perfectly drawn.

See for example: http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/